# Google Earth Plugin Scrolls Inappropriately on Web page

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Aside of any obvious themeing issues my poor site pages may have, this google earth plugin here scrolls over other page elements where as the rest act normally.

http://pt.meravista.com/en/algarve/information/sports-hobbies/ultimate-algarve-golf-tour

Does anyone recognize this behaviour and know a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The GEPlugin will render above all other elements as it isn't really in the DOM - it is a plugin that loads into the page (kinda like flash). If you don't want it to be over other elements then you would have to design your site so that it doesn't overlap with other things on your site.